DAX Studio - OrderBy column could not be resolved
I'm trying to calculate a rank for a table and use the rank to calculate a running total in DAX Studio.
I have an example using the Contoso Light model on Dax.do
https://dax.do/DcKq3ow0TUmm2W/
DEFINE
    VAR _SalesSummary =
        FILTER (
            SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
                'Date'[Year],
                'Product'[Category],
                'Product'[Product Name],
                "Sales Qty", [Total Quantity]
            ),
            'Date'[Year] = 2020
                && 'Product'[Category] = "Audio"
        )
    VAR _SalesSummaryWithRank =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            _SalesSummary,
            "QtyRank", RANKX ( _SalesSummary, [Sales Qty],, DESC, DENSE )
        )
    VAR _SalesSummaryWithRollingTotal =
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            _SalesSummaryWithRank,
            "Sales Qty RT", SUMX ( WINDOW ( 1, ABS, 0, REL, ORDERBY ( [QtyRank], ASC ) ), [Sales Qty] )
        )

EVALUATE
_SalesSummaryWithRank
ORDER BY [Sales Qty] DESC

/*EVALUATE
_SalesSummaryWithRollingTotal*/

I'm getting an error with the second EVALUATE statement, "OrderBy column 'QtyRank' could not be resolved."
What is the proper way to reference an added column in a subsequent query?

DEFINE Statement works with the immediate EVALUATE,  any following EVALUATE won't work unless you select the whole code or use a DEFINE specific to that EVALUATE.
